# Laravel - 500 Server Error when APP_DEBUG is false

Tags: php, laravel

One of route in my Laravel application start generating `500 | Server Error`.
I worked around it and tried to find out why is it happening. While doing different tests, I come to know that when I do set `APP_DEBUG is to false`, after that route is generating `500 | Server Error`.
When I do set `APP_DEBUG is to true` in .env file this error do not appear.

I tried to find out which line of code is creating problem, for that purpose I commented `return view()` and try to display all variables by `dd($data)`. `dd($data)` showed all varaible and their values properly there was no issue.

Then I tried to find what error is given in `Log` file, Log file error details are given below...

```
[2020-06-26 16:33:58] production.ERROR: Unexpected data found. {"userId":1387,"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Unexpected data found. at /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php:623)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php(645): Carbon\\Carbon::rawCreateFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '-0001-11-30 00:...', NULL)
#1 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/DateFactory.php(217): Carbon\\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '-0001-11-30 00:...')
#2 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(261): Illuminate\\Support\\DateFactory->__call('createFromForma...', Array)
#3 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(813): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('createFromForma...', Array)
#4 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(510): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->asDateTime('-0001-11-30 00:...')
#5 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(184): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->castAttribute('created_at', '-0001-11-30 00:...')
#6 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(104): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->addCastAttributesToArray(Array, Array)
#7 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1088): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->attributesToArray()
#8 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1117): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->toArray()
#9 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php(731): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model->jsonSerialize()
#10 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Support\\Collection->Illuminate\\Support\\Traits\\{closure}(Object(App\\Models\\User))
#11 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/EnumeratesValues.php(739): array_map(Object(Closure), Array)
#12 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Support\\Collection->jsonSerialize()
#13 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Watchers/RequestWatcher.php(206): json_encode(Array)
#14 [internal function]: Laravel\\Telescope\\Watchers\\RequestWatcher->Laravel\\Telescope\\Watchers\\{closure}(Array, 'total_registere...')
#15 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(638): array_map(Object(Closure), Array, Array)
#16 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Watchers/RequestWatcher.php(208): Illuminate\\Support\\Collection->map(Object(Closure))
#17 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Watchers/RequestWatcher.php(169): Laravel\\Telescope\\Watchers\\RequestWatcher->extractDataFromView(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#18 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Watchers/RequestWatcher.php(54): Laravel\\Telescope\\Watchers\\RequestWatcher->response(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Response))
#19 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(369): Laravel\\Telescope\\Watchers\\RequestWatcher->recordRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Events\\RequestHandled))
#20 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Events/Dispatcher.php(218): Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher->Illuminate\\Events\\{closure}('Illuminate\\\\Foun...', Array)
#21 /home/reseller/merilove/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(122): Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher->dispatch('Illuminate\\\\Foun...')
#22 /home/reseller/public_html/merilove.co.il/index.php(60): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 {main}
"}
```

I have tried to search in google and on stackoverflow against this error message (from log), but didn't get any useful information.

Given below is code of my controller

```
public function get_statistics(Request $reqeust) 
    {           
        $startDate = Carbon::now()->subDays((($reqeust['startDate'])?$reqeust['startDate']:0)); 
        $endDate = Carbon::now()->subDays((($reqeust['endDate'])? $reqeust['endDate'] : 0 )); 
        $data['startDate'] = $startDate;
                
        $data['SelectedDate'] = $startDate->format('d/m/y l');
        
        
        $data['endDate'] = $endDate; 
        $days = ($reqeust['date'])? $reqeust['date']: 1;
  
        
        $data['list_type'] = 'All Users List';
        $my_user_data = Auth::user();
        if ($my_user_data->membership != 2) { 
            return redirect()->route('home');
        } else {
            $data['todayDate'] = Carbon::now()->format('d/m/y');
            $data['time'] =  date('H:i:s');
            $data['startDate'] =  $reqeust['startDate']+1;
            $data['today'] =  1;
            $data['endDate'] =  $reqeust['endDate']-1;
            
            $ac = new AnalyticsController();
            $data['seven_day_visitors'] = $ac->seven_day_visitors();
            $data['total_active_users'] = $ac->activeVisitors()->totalsForAllResults['rt:activeUsers'];
            
            $data['total_registered_users'] =  $this->online_users();
            $data['total_customers'] = count($data['total_registered_users']['total_customers']);
            $data['total_register'] = count($data['total_registered_users']['total_register']);
            $data['total_visitors_now'] = 0;
            if($data['total_active_users']){
                $data['total_visitors_now'] = $data['total_active_users'] - $data['total_customers'];
                $data['total_visitors_now'] = $data['total_visitors_now'] - $data['total_register'];
            }
             

            $data['today_visitors'] = $ac->today_visitors();
            $data['unique_visitors'] = $ac->unique_visitors($startDate, $endDate);
            $data['today_register'] = count($this->today_register($startDate));
            $data['today_orders'] = count($this->today_orders($startDate));
            $data['traffic_soruces'] = $ac->traffic_sources($startDate, $endDate);
            // dd($data);
            
            return view('admin.dashboard', $data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't like one of your dates, from `Carbon\\Carbon::rawCreateFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '-0001-11-30 00:...`, when trying to save the User object, or something related to the user. It's not in this code here, so might be related to some middleware. Look for something related to Telescope.

Comment: Then why it do work work when APP_DEBUG is set to true?

Comment: I don't know, I'm just following the error trace.

Comment: See your error logs on `.../storage/logs`

Comment: @STA I have pasted log file data here. Please check it

Comment: I agree with @aynber Carbon can't pharse your given date. Error there

Comment: You might also want to check the database for any records for user 1387. It might be trying to parse a bad date coming back out

Comment: @aynber I have already tried with different accounts.